# When is $L^2(\Omega) = L^2(\bar \Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subset.

Is it always true that whenever $L^2(\Omega)$ is well defined that $L^2(\Omega) = L^2(\bar \Omega)$, where $\bar \Omega$, where $\bar \Omega$ means the closure of $\Omega$?

It seems true when eg. $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain since its closure just includes its boundary which is a null set. However, what if $\Omega$ is not as nice?

Comment: You should be careful, because strictly speaken, your equality can never be correct, it links spaces of functions with different domains of definition.

Comment: @Luke You're right... but I suppose we can think of elements in $L^2(\Omega)$ as functions that can be extended onto the closure of the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true if and only if $\bar\Omega \setminus \Omega$ has measure zero. One extreme case is the following: $\Omega$ is a countable, dense subset. Then, $$\{0\} = L^2(\Omega) \ne L^2(\bar\Omega) = L^2(\mathbb R^n).$$

Comment: Another counterexample would be $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with the counting measure.

Comment: @MichaelLee: I would assume that the OP implicitly uses the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Here's a possibly dumb question. What if the only difference between the two sets is a single point, but the measure of that point is infinite? For instance, $\Bbb R$ without zero. I am not sure if this can happen. It's too early in the morning for me to churn through measure theory in my head.